# APScheduler Background Scheduler Not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler, apscheduler

I am using background scheduler to schedule my jobs. When I am executing python script in the console the print statements are not executed. Is the scheduler being terminated? Below is my sample code

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def my_task1():
    print("Task 1")
def ny_task2():
    print("Task 2")
if __name__=='__main__':
     scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
     scheduler.add_job(my_task1, 'cron', id='my_task1', seconds=5)
     scheduler.add_job(my_task1, 'cron', id='my_task1', seconds=10)
     scheduler.start()
```

When I run the following script in the command line. I am not able to see the print statements in the console. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected a scheduler that runs in a background thread. Then you let the script exit. This is why nothing happens. The jobs have not had any time to be executed. Use `BlockingScheduler` instead if you want to keep the script running.

Comment: I have multiple jobs to schedule in a loop. Will BlockingScheduler serve this purpose?

Comment: Can you elaborate? At any rate, you will need to prevent the script from exiting, either by doing something else or using `BlockingScheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loop to keep it alive

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def my_task1():
    print("Task 1")
def ny_task2():
    print("Task 2")
if __name__=='__main__':
     scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
     scheduler.add_job(my_task1, 'cron', id='my_task1', seconds=5)
     scheduler.add_job(my_task1, 'cron', id='my_task1', seconds=10)
     scheduler.start()
     while True:
         time.sleep(1)
```